# Spring JPA - SQL Server Conversion from BLOB to varbinary(max) error

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to update my data in SQL server through spring JPA but it throws an error saying:--

**WARN - SQL Error: 8152, SQLState: 22001**

**ERROR - String or binary data would be truncated.**

Which happens because of a Pic field in the database having datatype varbinary (max) for which I'm using BLOB as its variable data type in the DTO file.

I'm using the save method from the crud repository to update records in the DB, which fails due to the above error. What should I do to fix it?

Employee DTO pic content--

```
    @Lob
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "")
    public Blob Profile_Pic;

    public Blob getProfile_Pic() {
        return Profile_Pic;
    }
    public void setProfile_Pic(Blob profile_Pic) {
        Profile_Pic = profile_Pic;
    }
```

Employee Update code---

```
portalEmployeeRepo.save(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use byte[] instead of a Blob in your entity class.

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "Profile_Pic", columnDefinition="BLOB")
public byte[] Profile_Pic;
```